# How to develop a crypto exchange leveraging on third party API like coinbase, blockchain.com

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, coinbase.com

I got a request as a developer to develop a bitcoin exchange site like https://mypatricia.co/ or https://instantcoins.ng/ I am to leverage on third party API like Coinbase, blockchain, it could be anything reliable API.

Users will be able to buy and sell bitcoin. For instance USER A makes an offer. USER B is interested in USER A's offer. When USER B clicks a button, with be a switch from USER A's wallet to USER B's wallet. Before the EXCHANGE is done. USER B is prompted to make payment in local currency.

I have been looking at https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#introduction https://api.blockchain.com/v3 I dont know how to go about it.

Is there any other better ones to work with?

There will be some other endpoints like

Where users get list of their orders
check wallet etc
I will appreciate your contribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are somewhat confused on what you want to build. You can either (try to) build an exchange that sources Bitcoin from an exchange like Coinbase or Blockchain and then sells them on for a markup. Or you can build a P2P exchange like Bisq, Paxful, LocalBitcoins etc. If you do the former it isn't P2P and it is subject to limits enforced by the API provider. If you do the latter you have no use for an API from Coinbase or Blockchain. [Bisq](https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq) is open source so you could look at their code if you want to understand how their P2P exchange works.